# Problem with GridView on Sharepoint

Tags: gridview

I tried to insert rows on GridView ASP.Net control. I tried this code:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["Nr"] = string.Empty;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);



GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

But i Getting this info:

**Column 'Nr' does not belong to table.**

Please help me, what i make wrong ? With GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. You have to mention column information.

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(Int32)));
tbl.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
row["ID"] = i;
row["Name"] = i + ". row";
tbl.Rows.Add(row);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I don't know why it don't get from asp formate the name of column.

Answer (score 0):

Define your DataColumn first:

```
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("Nr", typeof(String));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
```

Then insert value init and then add it in DataTable.

```
dr["Nr"] = string.Empty;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```